# Who is Rabenu Yonah Baal Tosfot

Tags: rishonim, tosfot, rabbeinu-yonah

In Tosfot Shabbat 39b, they cite Harav Rabenu Yonah:

> וה"ר יונה מפרש בטלה אפי' בקדירה חייתא והיינו דקאמר בטלה משמע לגמרי מכל דבר:‏

He is not in the list of Baale Tosfot in [Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA). He also seems to not be mentioned in [Shem Hagedolim](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=B1AqAAAAYAAJ&dq=%D7%A9%D7%9D+%D7%94%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D&printsec=frontcover&source=bl&ots=FsV695-CyJ&sig=49S6WLVagnQ0TAijOdQkXnpfX20&hl=iw&ei=EUpMS-X2GaiqmwOHpLjEDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result#v=onepage&q=%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94&f=false). I don't think it's the Rabenu Yonah Girondi who is from Chachme Sfarad.
Who is this Rabenu Yonah?

Comment: Tosafos also mentions Ibn Ezra, who was a Sefardi.

Comment: The Rosh was heavily influenced by Rabbeinu Yonah in his commentary to Bava Basra, and Tosafos Toques was a contemporary of his.

Comment: The Rosh on Berachot is almost build only on rabenu yonah

Answer (score 5):

According to R' Issar Kliger in the introduction to his book Rabbi Yehudah bar Ilai, pp. 32-33 it is indeed Rabbeinu Yonah of Girondi. He brings a list of other places in Tosfot where he's mentioned.

R' Yehudah Taub in Biurim Bedinei Shehiyah, Chazarah v'Hatmanah, [p. 139](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50478&st=&pgnum=142&hilite=) also quotes this Tosfot and refers to him as Rabbeinu Yonah.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yonah_Gerondi#Works), this was also the view of [Leopold Zunz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopold_Zunz).

Bear in mind that the Tosfot were still being compiled and edited well into the 14th-15th centuries if I'm not mistaken, and occasionally non-Tosafist rabbis are mentioned, so it's not such a wild thing to see him mentioned there.

Comment: +1 I see the Rav Taub quotes the Tosfot, but I don't understand what he adds. If the name Rabenu, the Tosfot himself writes ה' ר and this is the acronym of Harav Rabenu. This is not a Chiddush of the Rav Taub.

Comment: @kouty acronyms are tricky business. You interpret ה"ר as Harav Rabenu, but I typically read it as Harav Rabbi - הרב רבי. But yes, I suppose you could argue that it's not much proof. I would focus on Zunz and R' Kliger.

Comment: good point 15 characters